# offline voice recognization for voice calculator

Tags: android, speech-recognition, offline, calculator, voice-recognition

i am building an application "Voice Calculator" which takes input as a voice and display result based on the input. 
i dont want to use a google servers for voice recognization, is there any way through i can achive my goal.
i want to take input as " two plus three multiply four hundred twenty two minus one hundred" etc. so i would like to record and compare every words,
that can be converted in to text and which can be used to perform calculation.
can any one guide me , how to achive this? i am done with designing calculator with its functionality,
i hope i am able to explain my doubt, looking for help.. thank u..

Comment: Voice recognition is a very CPU intensive process. It is highly unlikely that anyone has a voice recognition engine for Android.

Comment: My company does, but the SDK for it would cost you more than you want to spend :)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but can any one help me building such app??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Google API for voice recognition, although I wanted an off-line version, I need to rely on voice recognition.
Have a look at [Voice Recognization for android example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/VoiceRecognition.html).

Answer (score 0):

Granted that not many device support it yet, but Jelly Bean will allow you to download Google's voice controls to the device for offline use.